# Function if and elseif to fulfill ".Body"

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

So I need to fulfill the ".Body" with the function if and elseif when an e-mail is sent via excel (macro on vba). 
At this point I have this. But it doesn't work, it does a"Syntax error". Can someone please help me identifying what's wrong?

```
Sub EnviarEmailEt4()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim Body As String

  Range("D2").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
     If ActiveCell >= 1 And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "" And InStr(4, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10), "@") > 0 Then

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

      With OutMail
            .To = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10).Value
            .CC = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11).Value
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
            .Body = If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then
                    .Body = "ALERTA PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value

                    ElseIf (ActiveCell >= 3) Then
                    .Body = "ULTRAPASSADO PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value

                    End If


     End If

    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You should post any error messages if there are any. But you do not need `MailBody = ` before the If.

Comment: *But it doesn't work* This is not helpful. What is not working? Does code arises any error while executing? We need more info. Help the community to help you :)

Comment: As mentioned by Andy you don't `MailBody =  ` . Also an `End with` is missing as well!

Comment: I've changed the code and the error is "Syntax error"

Comment: You should make `Then` the last word, push the following text to the line below, otherwise you are creating different versions of the statement(s).

Comment: I've done it and it does the same syntax error. look to the image up please

Comment: You have an `IF` statement to assign the value to `.Body` which in turns assigns the value to `.Body` within it. Removing `.Body =` should resolve your **Syntax Error**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need something like this in that case.

```
If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then
      .body = "ALERTA PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & _ Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
ElseIf (ActiveCell >= 3) Then
      .body = "ULTRAPASSADO PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & _ Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
End If
```

Edit 1:

The with statement should look like this :

```
With OutMail
    .To = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10).Value
    .CC = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 11).Value
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
    If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then
        .body = "ALERTA PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
    ElseIf (ActiveCell >= 3) Then
        .body = "ULTRAPASSADO PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
    End If
    .send
End With
```

Comment: it doens't work too, "syntax error" and puts in red this

" .Body = If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then"

Comment: That is the same error in syntax that I originally pointed out, and does not reflect @Arjun 's answer.

Comment: I didn't understand. You're saying that I did not the recomended you've told me?

Comment: The if condition `(If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then)` has to be written outside of the '.body' statement.

Comment: There was no error now. But it should be sending an e-mail and it did not happened

Comment: To send an email you need to add the .send function. [More Details can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.send(method))

Answer (score 0):

You asked exactly the same question one week ago. And the error in your code from last week was exactly the same as this question. I don't understand how you managed to have positive vote.

"x = if a then something else somethingelse" is not valid in VBA. Makes me wonder if you even wrote this code.

But whatever.
here is a working version.

```
Sub EnviarEmailEt4()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim Body As String

  Range("D2").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    If ActiveCell >= 1 And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "" And InStr(4, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10), "@") > 0 Then

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
            .To = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 10).Value
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
            If (ActiveCell = 1) Or (ActiveCell = 2) Then
                    .Body = "ALERTA PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value

            ElseIf (ActiveCell >= 3) Then
                    .Body = "ULTRAPASSADO PRAZO ETAPA 4!!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Nº GQE " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
            End If
    End With
End If
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

btw, you are never sending the email with this code. You need to add `OutMail.send` for that.

Comment: It is not the same. If it were, i would not ask. What I'm asking now it's a complement.
I never had this this kind of materia in my academic life. And in my organization, i needed to do something that requires VBA experience. And no, the original code it's not mine and I never said it was. I found this code and then I applied it to my reality, changing some points with the help of this comunity.
So if you don't  want to help, that's ok,  then I would like you to not do this kind of comments.